# C++ passing object by reference and casting

Tags: c++

I have an object of a base class which is actually pointing to a derived class like this

```
Base *b = new Derived()
```

What I want to know, is it possible to pass the base class pointer by reference to some function which can cast the object back to Derived class. Something like this

```
Dummy_cast_fn(&b) // casts b to derived class
```

After calling `Dummy_cast_fn`, `b` should have a full copy of Derived class (no slicing).

**Edit** 
I dont understand the part that there is no slicing since pointers are used. My problem is Derived class is returned from a function call to a shared library and I do not have access to .h file for the Derived. Only information I have is that Derived is based on Base class. I have access to Base.h so I can instantiate an object of Base but problem comes when I try to access the functions which are defined in Derived but not in Base. So I was wondering if I can typecast the Base to Derived type, then I will be able to access the function defined in Derived and not in Base.

Comment: you want a full copy, or a reference to the original?

Comment: Unless you store the pointer somewhere, why do you pass by pointer at all? Pass by reference instead …

Comment: I want full copy of the Derived.

Comment: @Konrad the pointer is stored in type of Base class, hence slicing is occurring. I cannot access the methods present in Derived but not present in Base. Hence I want to cast the Base pointer to Derived.

Comment: @Vivek That’s unrelated to passing via pointer vs. reference. Either will do fine, and will *not* slice the object. But whenever there’s a choice between using references and using pointers, references are preferred.

Comment: @konnard the issue is I am not able to call a function called sum present in Derived class when the pointer is instantiated with Base class. How can I do that...

Comment: How do you know what methods `Derived` implements if you don't have access to its definition?

Comment: That is what the author of the Derived wrote in the docs...

Comment: @VivekKhurana, this is a dead end. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `b` is a pointer or reference to a `Derived`, you can always:

1. Down cast it to a `Derived`.
2. Treat it as a `Base` as long as you're using `b`.

Namely, what determines what you can do with `b` is its static type, in this case `Base`. However, since it actually points on a `Derived`, you can always downcast it. Yet, to use it as a `Derived` you must have a variable whose type is `Derived` as well.

So, if the purpose of `Dummy_cast_fn` is just to fix something in `b` - it's useless. If an object is sliced, nothing can fix it. But in your case, there's no slicing, since you're using pointers.

Edit according to the question's edit:

First, you're `Derived` object is not sliced. Let's get that off the table. You have a pointer to a complete `Derived` (assuming that's what you've been passed), but you only have access to its `Base` part when using the `Base` pointer. Now, you say you don't have the definition of `Derived`. This means you won't be able to downcast to that type, because the compiler doesn't know how it's defined. No casting will work here. There's no legal C++ way you can call that `sum` function if you don't have `Derived`'s definition.

I do wonder why the author of `Derived` provided you its documentation without providing its definition. With this kind of polymorphism, the provider usually lets the user have some "interface", leaving the actual type as an internal implementation detail. If you can't use `Derived` because you don't have its definition, there's no point in letting you have its documentation.

Comment: I managed to get some more info on this. The whole idea is to build a plugin system which can invoke the plugin from a shared library without including the .h file thus not requiring any recompilation when ever a new plugin is added to the system. Think of plugin as capabilities, where capabilities can be added and loaded by parsing list of sub-directories to find what capabilities have to be loaded. All plugins will be base on Base class for which the definition is available. Think of this as something similar to import in Java or Python...

Comment: @VivekKhurana, this is exactly why only the `Base` is provided. It's the plugin interface, and that's the only thing the user should know. How exactly does the plugin provide the functionality is the plugin's business. If that `sum` method should be part of the plugin's functionality, it should be added to `Base`. Note that Java's import won't work if the imported class is not available.  Only difference is that in Java there's reflection, which can bypass the definition and investigate an unknown type. You don't have that in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a `Base*` into a `Derived*`, but you can get a `Derived*` pointing to the object that a `Base*` is pointing to, using `dynamic_cast`:

```
Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b);
if (d) {
  // cast was succesful
} else {
  // cast failed, 
  // e.g. because b* does not point to a Derived* but some other derived type
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the type of your `Base* b`, you can however create a new pointer

```
    Derived* p = static_cast<Derived*>(b);
```

and use that. Once `b` is declared as `Base*` you can't modify its type. You can also use `dynamic_cast` also although this is slower and may not strictly be necessary (although I cannot say for certain - that depends on your requirements). And if you are correctly using virtual functions you may not even need to do any casting at all - that is one of the purposes of polymorphism